# How new transaction will get recorded when all bitcoins are mined

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I am new to blockchain and learning about bitcoin & blockchain. As I understood that miners discovered new BLOCK and get the rewards as bitcoin and these BLOCKS are used to keep record of various transactions.

I also learned that there is a cap on max number of bitcoins (21 million) can be mined. This means there won't be any BLOCK left to record any new transaction. Does it mean that once all bitcoins are mined the blockchain will not be operational and no further transactions can be done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, after the completion of the bitcoin emission, miners will receive a reward from the fee for each transaction included in the block. This fee will need to be included in transactions.